# Mostrar suma de valores de Firebase Database en Kotlin

Tags: base-de-datos, firebase, kotlin

Tengo un Firebase Database montado con las diferentes compras que se realizan en la aplicación Android, a cada compra se le asigna un valor de puntos de forma que cada entrada en la Database se muestra de la siguiente forma:

[image: FireBase Database]

Cuando el userId se loguee tendrá un botón que debe mostrar su usuario y su cantidad de puntos llamando a la función showInfoClient. El código que tengo es:

```
private val database = Firebase.database
private val myref = database.getReference("compras")

fun showInfoClient(view: View) {

        val userlog = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.displayName
        val alertDialogInfo = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
        myref.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userlog).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :
            ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                var sum = 0
                for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    sum += data.child("puntos").getValue(Int::class.java)!!
                    Toast.makeText(this@Principal, sum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
        })

        alertDialogInfo.setTitle(userlog)
        alertDialogInfo.setMessage("Puntos: ") // + sum

        alertDialogInfo.setButton(
            AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK"
        ) { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }

        alertDialogInfo.show()

        val btnPositive = alertDialogInfo.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)

        val layoutParams = btnPositive.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        layoutParams.weight = 100f
        btnPositive.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }
```

He probado diferentes opciones pero no soy capaz de volcar el valor de sum en

```
alertDialogInfo.setMessage("Puntos: $sum")
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: en el Toast si te aparece?

Comment: Solucionado, fallo mío, en `myref.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userlog)....` estaba comparando email con DisplayName...